# Oracle 10g JDBC Insert / Update Date type column bug

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

Following is the environment that I have tried.
Oracle DB version: 10.2.0.3.0
JDBC JAR version: 10g Release (10.2.0.5), (10.2.0.4), (10.2.0.3), (10.2.0.2), (10.2.0.1.0) drivers
Java version: SE 1.4, SE 1.5, SE 6

Found a weird bug when I was testing out a simple SQL insert into an Oracle Date type column using JDBC. Whenever I use `PreparedStatement` and set the `java.sql.Timestamp` with a time between 23:30:00 to 23:59:59 from year 1970 to 1981 (any month & date will do), the `Date` value inserted into the database will be corrupted. However it works if I run a direct insert SQL.

Scenario A which doesn't work.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String sql = "INSERT INTO LABOR (LABORNAME, STARTTIME) VALUES (?, ?)";
c.set(1970, 1, 1, 23, 45);
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, "test");
pstmt.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis())); 
// Tried using new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime()), result is the same
pstmt.execute();
```

Scenario B which works.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO LABOR (LABORNAME, STARTTIME) VALUES ('TEST', TO_DATE('1970-01-01 23:55:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))";
con = getConnection();
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.execute();
```

Edited** Scenario C which works with JDBC 10g jar. Thanks to Mick Mnemonic for his comment.

[image]

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore");
String sql = "INSERT INTO LABOR (LABORNAME, STARTTIME) VALUES (?, ?)";
c.set(1970, 1, 1, 23, 45);
c.setTimeZone(tz);
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, "test");
pstmt.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis()), c); 
pstmt.execute();
```

**For Scenario A, I can't reproduce the same bug if I use an Oracle JDBC jar version 11g.** My question is that what's actually causing the problem.

PS: I searched thru the net and can't found anything related.

Comment: Seems like your JVM is using a different locele/timezone than the DB is.

Comment: please provide the "corrupted" entries you see

Comment: Try once more with the `setTimestamp` [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar)) that accepts a `Calendar` for defining the time zone.

Comment: Note that the month in Calendar.set() is zero-based which means that 1 = Feb.  While in your other examples January is equal to 1 as expected and sane.

Comment: @WW. The month does not really matter here. Using JDBC 10g, the problem persists as long as I insert a Date between year 1970 to 1981 with a Time between 2330 to 2359 without specifying the Timezone. However the same code for scenario A works if I use a JDBC 11g jar. So I'm curious what's wrong here.

Comment: What do you mean by corrupted?  Is there an exception?  is the data value just wrong?